# Change uri in cursor to load images from local dierctory

Tags: android

I downloaded example where gallery loaded images like

```
Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                  columns, null, null, orderBy);
```

When I print `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` I get:

```
content://media/external/images/media .
```

But how can I change to load from directory like:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test/";
```

I tried

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test/");
```

and

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("content:"Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test/");
```

but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: try using Uri.parse("/sdcard/test"); this is not right way to give hardcoded path..but you can just check

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
File ff = new File("/sdcard/test");

Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(Uri.fromFile(ff), columns, null, null, orderBy);
```